# Cómo podría escribir fórmulas matemáticas en Android Studio?

Tags: android

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Android Studio donde parte de la información que necesito mostrar son fórmulas matemáticas, había iniciado mostrándolo con imágenes pero ya eso se me queda corto, necesito saber como podría mostrarlo.

Comment: Por favor traduce el título de tu pregunta, pues estás en SO en español

Comment: Te invito a leer [ask], de paso checar también el [tour], la pregunta parece amplia y basada en opiniones ya que no muestras dudas claras y por eso pudiera terminar cerrada

Answer (score -2):

Conozco dos librerías que te podrían funcionar:

- [MathJax](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/Guide:-MathJax-in-Android-apps)
- [JqMath](https://inducesmile.com/android/how-to-display-math-formula-and-equation-in-android-application/)

La primera tiene una comunidad más activa pero también es una librería más pesada que la segunda.

Comment: Recuerda por favor que responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad, edita y mejora tu aporte

Comment: Creo que en este tipo de preguntas no hay nada más que aportar. Basta con una guía de próximos pasos. Dependiendo de sus necesidades elegirá si alguna le ayuda o no y si es el caso se documentará sobre dicha librería. No tiene un problema en concreto que resolver, no hay código que agregar. Finalmente, el fin es ayudar y creo que mi respuesta le ayudará bastante y eso es lo que importa.

Comment: Precisamente como lo mencionas: **no hay problema concreto a resolver y tampoco código**, entonces es seguro termine cerrada y por ende no se debe responder, tienes la suficiente reputación para dejarle estas recomendaciones en la zona de comentarios

Comment: Si lees la diferencia entre respuesta y comentario entonces entenderás por qué no lo puse ahí. Ahora, si se cerrará ¿cuál es el problema? ¿Para qué corregiste el título entonces?

Comment: Comentario final: se le pidió que tradujera pues es necesario para evitar se le cierre, posterior le indique lea como preguntar y le hice saber el motivo que puede llevar su pregunta a cierre; se le da oportunidad por que es nueva en la plataforma, lo que a ti te comento va en función de que en la comunidad se pide que no respondamos a preguntas tan amplias y que se pueden prestar a opiniones, además como ya debes saber responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad, no son mis reglas...